# templated parameter deduction in C++

Tags: c++11

Is there any way to construct this code so that I do not have to specify the template parameter of `bar`?

i.e. it does not currently compile, but will compile if I change `bar(v)` to `bar<int>(v)` in `main`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct foo
{
    foo(std::vector<T>& v)
    {
    }
};

template <class T>
void bar(const foo<T>& f)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    bar(v); // does not compile
    bar<int>(v); // compiles but is undesirable

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is only allowed one implicit conversion but you can add an overload for `bar` that tries to convert whatever you give it to a `foo` and then calls your original `bar` with the temporary `foo` (which is what would happen if two implicit conversions was allowed in your original code):

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T& v) {
    return bar(foo(v));
}
```

Since the conversion constructor in `foo` doesn't take the argument by `const&`, neither can this `bar` overload.